# multiple redirects with favicon crashing apache, using PHP5 and Kohana

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am not sure who the culprit is, but here's the apache error log using `LogLevel Debug`:

```
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 68.178.109.243] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 68.178.109.243] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 68.178.109.243] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 68.178.109.243] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 68.178.109.243] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 68.178.109.243] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 68.178.109.243] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/favicon.ico/favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 68.178.109.243] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 68.178.109.243] redirected from r->uri = /favicon.ico
[Tue Jul 13 11:51:18 2010] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 68.178.109.243] Zlib: Compressed 624 to 387 : URL /index.php/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico
```

favicon.ico keeps getting redirected and after 10 it errors out. This is a rewrite rule that, as far as I know, is working on the dev remote server but seems to be crashing on my local setup. Any idea where I can go to start debugging this?

Edit: Here's the rewrite rule for favicon:

`RewriteRule ^(.+/)favicon\.ico$ favicon.ico`

So what this is stating is any string that preceding favicon.ico should be redirected to favicon.ico, is that correct? Admittedly the regex-ness of it throws me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the .htaccess file that contains the rewrite rules. It seems to be triggering a recursive rewrite.

EDIT:

Try changing your rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+/)favicon\.ico$ favicon.ico [L]
```

That should halt the recursive rewrite.

Comment: it still does it multiple times, but instead of going favicon.ico/favicon.ico/favicon.ico/ and so on, it stays at /favicon.ico, thanks.

the reason it does it multiple times is prob an error in my code

Comment: My rewrite-fu isn't good enough to deduce why you're getting multiple requests, but the [L] stops a recursive request.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess i guess. redirecting a favicon in php code would be crazy imo.

edit:

just tested this .htacces and it works perfectly (ko3)

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>
RewriteRule ^(.+/)favicon.ico$ favicon.ico

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b - [F,L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```